# How to convert unix timestamp column to date format in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to obtain the results in yyyy-mm-dd format from unixtimestamp column but getting in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

My data in receive_time column is following:

```
recieve_time

1557866863  |
1557866863  |
1557866863  |
1557866863  |
1557866864  |
1557866864  |
1557866864  |
1557866864  |
```

Following is my query:

```
SELECT
to_timestamp(recieve_time) as date, count(*)
 FROM public.cdrs WHERE 
usage_type='0800 Voice Incoming' 
and to_timestamp(recieve_time) >='2019-05-01 00:00:00'
AND to_timestamp(recieve_time) <'2019-06-01 00:00:00'
AND main_bzd >0 
group by to_timestamp(recieve_time)
```

Getting this:

```
date                 |count|

-------------------|-----|

2019-05-01 00:00:2 |1    |
2019-05-01 00:03:2 |1    |
2019-05-01 01:20:0 |1    |
2019-05-01 01:21:1 |1    |
2019-05-01 01:53:0 |1    |
2019-05-01 02:16:5 |1    |
2019-05-01 02:33:5 |1    |
2019-05-01 02:39:4 |1    |
2019-05-01 02:55:3 |1    |
2019-05-01 03:32:5 |1    |
2019-05-01 03:35:0 |1    |
```

My requirement is following:

```
date        |count|

------------|-----|

2019-05-01  |19   |
2019-05-02  |15   |
2019-05-03  |17   |
```

Comment: There is no such [column data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)  `unixtimestamp` in Postgres.

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Comment: *Don't* store integers instead of dates. Use the correct type. SQL, the language, and all databases have date types. The integer you stored may be called "unix timestamp" but we don't know if it represents seconds, or milliseconds - never mind the epoch.

Comment: Apologise i'm posting the column data from my table

Comment: What's worse, the query you want to perform will have to scan the entire table without benefiting from indexes, because `to_timestamp(recieve_time) >='2019-05-01 00:00:00'` works on the output of a function, not the indexed value itself. To make this query run fast you'd have to convert the date values into integers

Comment: @BaljotSingh the solution is to use proper dates and times, not integers. No matter what you may have heard, they are neither common nor interoperable

Comment: ok..but the data stored in table is by my client ..i can only perform select procedures to make a report

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cast the result to `date`, both in the `SELECT` list and the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
CAST(to_timestamp(recieve_time) AS date)
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the simplest way to convert a unix timestamp to date format in PostgreSQL is below:

```
select to_timestamp(1557866863)::date;
 to_timestamp 
--------------
 2019-05-15
(1 row)
```

So your complete SQL would be:

```
select
     to_timestamp(recieve_time)::date as date,
     count(*)
from 
    public.cdrs 
where 
    usage_type='0800 Voice Incoming'
    and receive_time >= extract(epoch from cast('2019-05-01 00:00:00' as timestamptz))
    and receive_time <  extract(epoch from cast('2019-06-01 00:00:00' as timestamptz))
    and main_bzd >0 
group by 
    to_timestamp(recieve_time)::date
```

Notice: if there is a `index` created on your `receive_time` column, you'd better do not use the function on `receive_time` when it located at the `where` clause to filter rows, it will lead to fail to use index when execute SQL, the way above in my SQL is a better way. Good luck !

Comment: @BaljotSingh I have given some advise in my answer above, hope helpful for you. :D

Answer (score 4):

For formating date you should use function "to_char"
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-formatting.html
It support time formating, or you can use extract to separate date part.

```
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp( 156049813956389/100000), 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: drop a couple of zeros `SELECT to_char(to_timestamp( 1525202258000/1000), 'yyyy-mm-dd')`